# Regex to remove a whole phrase from the match

Tags: regex

I am trying to remove a whole phrase from my regex(PCRE) matches

if given the following strings

```
test:test2:test3:test4:test5:1.0.department
test:test2:test3:test4:test5:1.0.foo.0.bar
user.0.display
"test:test2:test3:test4:test5:1.0".division
```

I want to write regex that will return:

```
.department
.foo.0.bar
user.0.display
.division
```

Now I thought a good way to do this would be to match everything and then remove `test:test2:test3:test4:test5:1.0` and `"test:test2:test3:test4:test5:1.0"` but I am struggling to do this

I tried the following

```
\b(?!(test:test2:test3:test4:test5:1\.0)|("test:test2:test3:test4:test5:1\.0"))\b.*
```

but this seems to just remove the first tests from each and thats all. Could anyone help on where I am going wrong or a better approach maybe?

Comment: Maybe replace `"?test:test2:test3:test4:test5:1\.0"?` with an empty string? See https://regex101.com/r/EaWJ8I/2

Comment: Yeah I think it may have to be done with replacements. Thank you @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest searching for the following pattern:

```
"?test:test2:test3:test4:test5:1\.0"?
```

and replacing with an empty string. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EaWJ8I/2) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%22%3Ftest%3Atest2%3Atest3%3Atest4%3Atest5%3A1%5C.0%22%3F):

[image]

The quotation marks on both ends are made optional with a `?` (1 or 0 times) quantifier.